# prestashop cart summary table

Tags: css, html-table, prestashop

I work on a copy of default boostrap theme on prestashop. I've a problem with responsive table... I don't know why but my tables have a horizontal scroll. They don't "move" like in the original theme when you are on a mobile phone. The site is [catapart](http://www.catapart.fr) when you are on the cart summary. It is like this:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to not have horizontal scroll:

[image: screenshot]

I tried everything but... no solutions!

Comment: This is how responsive bootstrap table works (it has a horizontal scrollbar).

Comment: @kek I added the second image to your post, which was in the source but not visible in the question itself (and made some tiny changes to reference the image). Please let me know if this is what you meant, or edit if I misunderstood your intentions. (Also: traditionally hand-drawn circles on images posted to SO are in red, not blue;)